# Why do the Pyproj and Haversine methods to calculate heading from two lat/lon points differ from what Google Earth displays?

Tags: python, geopy, pyproj

I am trying to implement a short python function to calculate the heading between two points.  In other words if I am at point one, what heading relative to true north would I need to take to get to point two.  I have used the following Python implementation which gives me essentially the same results.

```
from pyproj import Geod
lat1 = 42.73864
lon1 = 111.8052
lat2 = 43.24844
lon2 = 110.6083
geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84')
# This implements the highly accurate Vincenty method
bearing = geod.inv(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)[0]
# >>> 60.31358
```

I have also used the following code that uses a Haversine method

```
from math import degrees, radians, sin, cos, atan2

def bearing(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    lat, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon1])
    dLon = lon2 - lon1
    y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2)
    x = cos(lat1)*sin(lat2) - sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(dLon)
    brng = degrees(atan2(y, x))
    if brng < 0: brng += 360.0
    return brng
```

With the same inputs from the previous implementation I get a result of 60.313 degrees, which matches the first implementation. However, when I use the Ruler function in google earth I get a result of 15.71 degrees.  Furthermore when I activate the grid on google earth that shows the lines of longitude as a reference, 15.71 degrees makes far more sense.  Why does the Google Earth implementation differ from the Python implementations?

Comment: Maybe ask over at [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the outputs of your `geod` code part are correct.
try to get behind it using easy examples (see below):

this means that there was probably a problem entering the coordinates into google earth or setting up the ruler but not in your code.

```
lat1 = 40
lon1 = 40
lat2 = 39
lon2 = 40

#output 180.0
```

or

```
#Kansas City:
lat1 = 39.099912 
lon1 = -94.581213
#St Louis:
lat2 = 38.627089
lon2 = -90.200203

#output 96.4809
```

the second example can be confirmed on this page:
https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/